# Partial commit or skip in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I have a scenario where in i have a session created using an sqlalchemy engine . Now i am looping through 10 insert statements nd in 2nd statement i am getting constraints error .. I want this particular insert to be skipped and rest of the insert statements  to continue.

I am using python and doing it in try catch block but still the session is getting errored and not moving ahead.

Any suggestions on this.

I tried placing flush and rollbacks before moving ahead with other inserts still  i am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested transactions to set [savepoints](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint), allowing actions within the nested transaction to be rolled back without affecting the outer transaction.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import exc
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, Mapped, DeclarativeBase, sessionmaker


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't75313967'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.Identity(), primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True)


engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test', echo=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)


names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Carol']

with Session() as s, s.begin():
    for name in names:
        try:
            with s.begin_nested():
                s.add(Test(name=name))
        except exc.IntegrityError:
            print(f'Skipping {name}')
```

Comment: i am getting session transaction object has no attribute add error

i had a session object
I just did sessionnested =session.begin_nested()

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy do you have?